# getting percent ('%') characters and unicode codepoints in HTTP response

Tags: json, unicode

I'm connecting to a HTTP API through a simple GET request.

The expected response is a string, representing a JSON, that may contain hebrew (unicode) characters, but i get something like this  (pasted only the beginning):

```
%u007b%u0020%u0022%u0053%u0074%u0061%u0074%u0075%u0073...
```

the result is the same whether i use ajax or the browser navigation bar directly.

The only place i get the expected json string is in Firefox console, by logging the response object, selecting it, and viewing the responseText property. 
I can also replace the percent characters with backslashes, put the result in a unicode parser and get the correct string.

Anybody has any ideas as to what is going on?

Comment: How do you get that string? You shouldn't get it. If you decode it then it looks like the beginning of a json object: `s.replace('%u', '\\u').decode('unicode-escape')` -> `{ "Status`

Comment: Yep, i didn't get an answer from the developers of the service yet, but it looks like some kind of weird hybrid between URL encoding and unicode... Maybe just a (very weird) choice on their part. Meanwhile i use the solution suggested above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The response appears to be encoded with the deprecated javascript function [escape()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#Escape_sequences) which yields the %uXXXX encoding.  If that is the case then the service should instead use encodeURIComponent() or encodeURI() referenced in the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#Escape_sequences) above.
Your current workaround of manual un-encoding is the right way to go until the service is updated.